# ASP.NET 4 changes with automatic names of controls

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

I just updated an app from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0 and I have noticed the following.

For example I have the following control:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$hfdFueraHorarioOficinaConfirmado" 
 id="cphMain_hfdFueraHorarioOficinaConfirmado" value="False" />
```

and then in javascript I did this before:

```
 var hfdFueraHorarioOficinaConfirmado=document.getElementById('ctl00_cphMain_hfdFueraHorarioOficinaConfirmado');
```

but after checking the `id` within the html source once it renders and also doing some debugging with firebug etc it has changed from:

```
ctl00_cphMain_hfdFueraHorarioOficinaConfirmado
```

to:

```
cphMain_hfdFueraHorarioOficinaConfirmado
```

Can anyone explain why? Should I basically do a search and replace and remove the `ctl00`?

Obviously the javascript line with the `ctl00_` in front returns null because it doesn't exist, but removing this returns the object.

Any help or ideas really appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There have been some changes, which look like for the better, but Microsoft have created a compatibility flag you can set to retain backwards compatibility with .NET 3.5 - [see this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx).

You can set the `ClientIDMode` property to `AutoID` in your web.config file to retain the previous behaviour, and override it on individual controls gradually as you start to make changes throughout your code.

Answer (score 1):

In your script files, you should look at always using the ClientID that you get on the server side (and output as a script variable on the page).

I think that there are also ways of setting how the control naming is done in 4.0, you might be able to pick a setting that solves your problem:

http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx

Comment: General article about the cleaner HTML...

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net automatically generates client IDs for server-side controls.

As you've discovered, you must not rely on these automatically generated names staying the same.

In ASP.Net 4.0, you can set the [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28VS.100%29.aspx) property to `Static`.  Your ID will then be used untouched as the client-side ID.

In all versions of ASP.Net, you should use the `ClientID` property instead of hard-coding the ID.

For example: (In the ASPX page)

```
var hfdFueraHorarioOficinaConfirmado = 
    document.getElementById('<%= hfdFueraHorarioOficinaConfirmado.ClientID %>');
```

Comment: That's not exactly true of Static.  It *may* be changed depending on the container.

Comment: @Chris: No; it will never be changed.

Comment: I hate to differ. But if you have a label control in a repeater, the ID of the Label will change regardless of whether ClientIDMode is Static or AutoID. The repeater's name will be prepended. Therefore, it is dependent on what the parent of your control is.

Comment: @Chris: Only if the control is being repeated for databinding.

Comment: ergo.. It *may* be changed depending on the container.