# Control Names on QueryString different in IIS-8 Classic Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, iis-8, asp.net-controls

We have moved an application from Windows Server 2003 with IIS-6 to a new Windows 2012 Server with IIS-8 and setup the App Pool for "Classic".  My problem is that the existing code pulls a value off the query string in a controller method using the querystring.

```
string tmpID= Request[string.Format("DisabilityRepeater:_ctl{0}:ddDisability", num)];
```

I have hit the old and new site and the format of the control has changed.  This is consistently different between the platforms and not affected by browser.

For example here is the name from the querystring in IIS-6:

```
DisabilityRepeater:_ctl1:ddDisability
```

and from IIS-8:

```
DisabilityRepeater$ctl01$ddDisability
```

I have searched for some "breaking change" to the name munging but have been unable to find a solution in the configuration.

I could make a code change, however we are migrating all application currently on Server 2003 to Server 2012 and this includes about 75 applications and so a configuration update would be preferable.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET forms app? What version of ASP.NET was the site running under on Windows 2003, and what version on your new 2012 server?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629770/net-asp-net-4-changes-with-automatic-names-of-controls

Comment: This is on an ASP.Net forms application.  It is running .Net 2.0/3.5 on both servers.  I also found some documentation about changing the pages tag in the web.config to contain the ClientIDMode=AutoID, and I am looking into that as well.